# If $a$ is a group element and $a^{6}=e$, why can't $|a|=4?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $a$ is a group element and $a^6=e$. What are the possibilities for $|a|?$ Intuitively, I know that the possibilities would be $1$, $2$, $3$ and $6$. But I  still can't disprove the possibility that $|a|=4$, for example.

Comment: Were $|a|=4,$ then $a^{4}=e,$ so $e=a^{6}=a^{2},$ which would imply $|a|\leq 2,$ a contradiction.

Comment: If $|a|=4$ that means that $a^2\neq e$. So $a^6=a^4a^2\neq e$.

Comment: is that the order of $a$? If so, then if $a^n = e$, then $\mbox{ord}a\mid n$. Clearly $4\mid 6$ doesn't hold.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: you're correct, it's clear that $4|6$ doesn't hold. I just wanted to understand the reasoning behind the "contradiction" proof, when we suppose that $a^{4}=e$. It was difficult to put that into words, though.

Comment: @Sharon Because $<a>$ is subgroup. We have no a contradiction in math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a^4 =e$ then $a^2 = a^2e = a^2a^4 = a^6 =e$, so $|a| \le 2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

If $a^6 = e$ and $a^4=e$, then 
$$e = a^6 = (a^2)(a^4) = (a^2)e = a^2$$
so the order of $a$ is not $4$.

Answer (score 1):

If so then we need $6$ is divisible by $4$ because $<a>$ is a subgroup, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=e$, then $|a| = 1$.

If $a\neq e$, $|a|=4$, then $a^4 = e$. But $e =a^6 = a^2e=a^2$, so $|a|=2$.